# Blank Crosh Problem

Tags: chromeos

When loading up crosh in Chrome OS, crosh is just completely blank. No text or anything. I just get the resolution pop up but thats about it. I kinda need crosh to be able to run Ubuntu. How do I fix this so I can run it again? Does it have to do with my version? I have Chrome OS version Dev 68.0.3431.0 and Ubuntu version Trusty 14.04 (I know. Its old).

Comment: Can you explain why do you “need crosh to be able to run Ubuntu” if you have Ubuntu installed already?

Comment: I need to enter the system shell using crosh so I can enter "sudo startunity" to launch Ubuntu.

Comment: If you have installed Ubuntu [using Crouton](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/12/install-ubuntu-on-your-chromebook-using.html), how did you run the previous commands? However, I must warn you that installing and booting such type of Ubuntu seems to be [off-topic here](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/14079/250300). You might want to try [su] instead.

Comment: I was able to use the terminal before but after updating the Chromebook it just stopped working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on the tab that you have crosh open in, open developer tools and run the following in the console (This will have to be run each time you open an instance of crosh, until the accessibility method gets fixed on the dev branch):

```
Crosh.init = function() {
  const qs = lib.f.parseQuery(document.location.search);
  const profileName = qs['profile'];
  var terminal = new hterm.Terminal(profileName);

  terminal.decorate(document.querySelector('#terminal'));
  const runCrosh = function() {
    terminal.keyboard.bindings.addBinding('Ctrl-Shift-P', function() {
      nassh.openOptionsPage();
      return hterm.Keyboard.KeyActions.CANCEL;
    });

    terminal.setCursorPosition(0, 0);
    terminal.setCursorVisible(true);
    terminal.runCommandClass(Crosh, qs['args'] || []);

    terminal.command.keyboard_ = terminal.keyboard;
  };
  terminal.onTerminalReady = function() {
    runCrosh();

  };

  // Useful for console debugging.
  window.term_ = terminal;
  console.log(nassh.msg(
      'CONSOLE_CROSH_OPTIONS_NOTICE',
      ['Ctrl-Shift-P', lib.f.getURL('/html/nassh_preferences_editor.html')]));

  return true;
};

Crosh.init();
```

Answer (score 0):

Previous answer did not work for me.  Acer C710 q1vzc.  I ran crouton via Dev Mode terminal (CTRL-ALT-F2) to install Ubuntu.

To start it though, you have to be in the ChromeOS GUI.

WORKAROUND:
I used an SSH Chrome extension to ssh chronos@localhost and ran the command from there.  In my case, the xfce version.

```
sudo startxfce4
```

Default version is Unity:

```
sudo startunity
```